# Регистрация пользователя с использованием JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать регистрацию пользователя на своем сайте.
Я новичок, интересует логика и используемые технологии.

Например я понимаю что сама форма это HTML
внешний вид формы это CSS
проверка полей формы это или CSS или JS

но я не понимаю что дальше?

как сохранять данные с формы ? это js или какие есть варианты?
как передать данные? это ajax или какие еще есть варианты?
как и куда сохранять данные? это sql или mongo DB?

те пожалуйста помогите понят процесс что понять куда рыть чтобы реализовать регистрацию на сайте и сохранять данные пользователей в базу.

Comment: Если очень кратко: При клике "регистрация" берете все данные с `input`'ов с помощью js, отправляете все данные на сервер, там уже закидываете все данные в нужные ячейки

Comment: что отправляет данные на сервер? и что взаимодействует с базой данных?

Comment: у вас что сервер  на node?  обычно на сервер  php  или c# ( наиболее распросроненые)

Comment: у вас код есть сюда покажите

Comment: @BigD, запросы, ajax, fetch, xmlh, смотря на чем у Вас сервер. python, node, php, c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаёте `html` документ (например `index.php` в который содержит `html` разметку). В котором вставляете форму так:

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Описание тегов вы найдёте [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/) (толковый ресурс для старта). В атрибуте `action` вы указываете путь к файлу (ресурсу) которому передать данные. В нашем случае это файл **PHP** (лежит в той же директории). Когда вы нажмёте на кнопку (`<button>`) браузер отправит данные на сервер где их будет принимать наш `form.php`. Атрибутом `method="post"` указываем как передавать.

На серверной стороне данные попадут в глобальный массив **$_POST**. Вытащить их можно так:

```
<?php

$login = htmlspecialchars (trim ($_POST['login']));
$password = htmlspecialchars (trim ($_POST['password']));
$password = md5 ($password);
```

Вытаскиваем данные из глобального массива по именам инпутов (помните `name="login"` и `name="password"`) с минимальной защитой. Подробнее о функциях - [тут](http://php.net/). Пароль обязательно хэшируйте.

Для занесения данных в таблицу (**mysql**) её необходимо создать. Рекомендую при текущем уровне знаний создавать таблицу на удалённом хостинге где есть **phpMyAdmin**. В ней это делается очень просто, а так же выводятся команды которые выполнились на языке **sql**. Предположим мы создали базу данных и в ней таблицу `users`. В таблице должно быть три колонки: `id`, `login`, `password`. `id` уникальный номер пользователя, его необходимо сделать `AUTO_INCREMENT`, чтобы при добавлении записей `id` новой записи увеличивался на 1.

Теперь используя [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php) занесём туда логин и пароль нашего нового пользователя.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( login, password ) VALUES ( :login, :password )";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
```

Мы не передали id так как он автоматически запишется.

Это очень простой пример регистрации. Но алгоритм действий именно такой при работе с PHP.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, думаю он многим пригодится как и мне =)

Comment: @BigD главное, чтобы вам понятно было.